# Best methodology for storing files from website and then push to CRM

Tags: database, file, cdn, methodology

Currently from our website users upload files (images, pdf etc)
These will be pushed to our CRM system

Current approach is, we are storing the uploaded files in blob stream in our database and then from windows service we are pushing to CRM systems and clearing off the blob stream from our database to improve disc space

So, Wanted to know what is the best solution for the above approach as storing the blob in database is not a good practice

In short - store uploaded files temporarily (database or CDN or filesystem ?) and push to other systems from our windows service. what/where is the best approach to store uploaded files?

Any inputs would be helpful

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is rather wide, and mostly opinion based - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Comment: I have rephrased my question. Is it fine now ?